# Проблемы с кодировкой Windows-1251

Tags: c, windows, cp1251

Русские символы возвращают отрицательные коды, вместо кодов от 192 до 255. system("chcp 1251"); прописано. Как использовать нормальные коды вместо отрицательных?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте `unsigned char`.

Comment: Используйте wchar_t

Comment: нет, скорее всего нужно `"%u",(unsigned int)c`

Answer (score -1):

```
/* Если у вас Windows!!!
Вот так и printf("Введите:"); не будет выводить краказябры
и коды символов будут такие как вы хотите.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "RU");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
int total=-1;
wchar_t ch;
printf("Введите текст:\n");
while((ch=getchar( ))!='\n')
{
    total++;
    if(total%8==0)
         putchar('\n');
    putchar(ch);
    printf("-%d ",ch);
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы понимаете разницу между кодировками? Чем отличается MultiByte от Unicode? Такой ерунды я ещё не видел. Помимо этого читайте вопрос и отвечайте именно на вопрос, а не предлагайте сделать из X, Y.

Comment: В вопросе человек попросил помочь использовать коды символов такие как ему хочется. Я показал какие файлы заголовка надо подключать и как представлять переменную. И представил готовый код без заморочек который выводит сразу всё как надо. Какие ещё могут быть вопросы о кодировках и прочих высших материях. Уберите свой минус и не несите чепуху.

Comment: И сами внимательно читайте вопрос автора. Никто никого не просит устраивать ликбез по кодировкам. Вопрос простой . "Как использовать нормальные коды вместо отрицательных?" Цитирую для особо одарённых.

Comment: Если вы до сих пор работаете на М5000 это совсем не значит что так должны делать все.

Comment: `getchar` возвращает букву типа `char`, записанную в тип `int`. Вы зачем-то этот `int` пишете в переменную типа `wchar_t`. Это совсем не в тему. Функция `putchar` берёт тип **`int`** переводит в `char` и печатает. Правильно так : `int ch;`

Comment: ... букву типа char записанную в тип int... Вы о чём, уважаемый?  Потрудитесь скомпилироваться мой код потом подумайте почему он делает то что от него хотят. Потом возьмите Стива Пратта и поучите что к чему.

Comment: Язык Си. Лекции и упражнения. 6 издание. Очень рекомендую. А то потом здесь умники с сумасшедшим рейтингом утверждают что \n это 2 символа а не один.